# How to write Regular expression with duplicate char in .* before end all chars?

Tags: php, regex

I have problem with regex.

My string: `"[312ds31spacer13d][TestWord]"`

In PHP I'm using:

```
preg_replace('#\[(.*)spacer(.*)]# ', '', $myString);
```

And this removed the entire string. How to leave `"[TestWord]"`?

Comment: Just make thsearch not greedy: `preg_replace('#\[.*?spacer.*?]# ', '', $myString);`

Comment: Thanks man, you won: D
Today I started learn about regex, so maybe for you it is easy problem but for me is hard at start.

Comment: You'll find usefull informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/372239) and [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)